# How to evaluate dimensionality reduction technique?

Tags: matlab, binary, dimensionality-reduction

I have a dataset of NxM data in binary form. I apply a variety of dimensionality techniques on it and I plot the first two dimensions. This is how I get an intuition of whether the technique is suitable for my dataset or not. Is there a more appropriate/methodical/heuristic/formal way to test the suitability of the dimensionality reduction techniques I use?

Comment: Why use mathlab at all? It seems efficient and powerfull but it is also helpful? You need to pay the price for a black box solution.

Comment: what do you recommend?

Comment: I would like to pay for it but I'm a poor man.

Answer (score 1):

The main purpose of applying dimensionality reduction on data is to **capture the original data's distribution** as much as possible **even after the dimensionality reduction**. Therefore, we want to make sure that **we capture the variance of the data as much as we can**.

Let's say you have a N*N matrix, and we perform SVD ([Singular Value Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition)) on X. Then, we'll observe the singular values, the diagonal entries in the resulting S matrix. (**X = USV**)

And you want to cut them off at some index K **based on the desired percentage variance captured:**

∑ <sub>i=1</sub> <sup>K</sup>  sigma(i) / ∑ <sub>i=1</sub> <sup>N</sup>  sigma(i)

If you select **the first K columns of U**, then you are reducing your original N-dimension to K-dimension.

Answer (score 0):

You could use SOM technique to be able to see several dims in two dimensions. There are other techniques also, I will update the answer if I can remember their name, but I am used to SOM.

[You can find one good SOM toolbox for matlab clicking here.](http://www.cis.hut.fi/somtoolbox/)

This helps you to visualize, but the evaluation should use an efficiency meter that measure what is important for your dimension reduction (the SOM itself may be used as a dimension reduction technique). What is important, to compress data with minimal loss? To compress data as most as possible? To represent data in a visible way? You can probably measure the techniques efficiency without needing to see how did them changed the data space representation, all you need is a good function to measure how good your technique is.